# Open dropdown at a time in reactjs from a map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a page where I have buttons and dropdowns. The way they are displayed is through a map function and ternary operator. The data in the dropdown is also from the array.

```
array.map 
if dropdown === 1 ?
   <div className="dropdown">
   </div>
: button
```

I have declared several stuff to work with the dropdown like

```
 const toggleDropdown = () => setOpen(!isOpen);
 const [items, setItem] = useState(Array);
 const [isOpen, setOpen] = useState(false);
 const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = useState(null);
```

Now, the problem is, since i have more objects that are **dropdown**, when i open one of it, other open as well.
How can I differentiate them, or create like an active state for the specific clicked dropdown.
If you have any idea with modifying the array to be able differentiate the dropdowns somehow please let me know.

I need the answer working with react hooks because i'm not familiar with the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a dropdown component that you can use everywhere and have whatever is including it open or close it.

```
const Dropdown = ({items, selected, open}) => {
  return <div className='dropdown'>
    // use items and selected here to create dropdown
  </div>
}
```

Now you can import that everywhere and just pass down the items, selected item and whether or not it's open from whatever component is using it.